# How to Combine/Join Data from Kafka with the Data from Bigquery in GCP dataflow?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to read data from a Kafka topic in a dataflow job and enrich the data with a data available in Bigquery and send the data to another Kafka topic. I need to apply a Fixed window of 1 minute while reading from Kafka. My Bigquery table gets updated in every 1 hour. How can I do this in a streaming dataflow job as one source is an unbounded Pcollection(Kafka) and another source of data is a bounded PCollection(Bigquery)?
I can't use a sideInput as my Bigquery table is huge.

Comment: My 2 cents ... BQ is not a transactional database.  If you have a high volume of Kafka messages and want to perform a query against BQ for **each** message, then it is likely you don't want the data in BQ.  Consider a transactional database (eg. Cloud SQL) and using Beam JdbcIO.    How much data is in the BQ table?  What is the rate of messages?  How is the message to be enriched?  What latency do you need?  Can we batch the Kafka messages?

Comment: @Kolban Our analytic data resides in bigquery and Cloud SQL can't be used. The table size varies from pipeline to pipeline. on an average it will be around 50-100GB. The messages are published  on an average of 50 message/second.  For these Kafka messages, the bigquery table is used for enriching/deriving some additional attributes and it is sent to another kafka topic for a real-time use case. I am using a fixed window of 1 minute while reading the kafka message. Is it technically possible to achieve this use case with Bigquery?

Comment: Am I understanding that you would like to make approx 50 BigQuery queries per second (one for each incoming message and using the content of that message as a parameter in a query?).  If yes ... then the answer is NO .. you can not use BigQuery for that.   BigQuery is optimized for LARGE and COMPLEX queries involving aggregations and not for ultra fast (a few 10s of milliseconds) lookups.  That would be best achieved with an operational database.

Comment: @Kolban, I want to execute a single query for the whole records in that specific window. For example in a window of 1 minute, I will get nearly ~2500 records from the Kafka topic. and for those 2500 records, a single query needs to be fired on the bigquery and use the result to combine the data from kafka. I don't need the query to run for each records, but instead it should  run once for a list of records within the window.  Is this possible?

Comment: I am sensing you want to provide an input list of 2500 values and get back an output list of 2500 corresponding "looked up" values.  I'm smelling creating a table of the 2500 input values and then joining that table with your reference table to get the results.   I'm sensing that you could then batch up the work into "1 minute" batches.  It feels like this may be possible but I'd suggest you write up a design and examine it for issues and run some experiments.

Comment: Hi @Kolban, Thanks for your input. As you mentioned earlier, I am thinking to avoid Bigquery direct read from the streaming dataflow job. Instead thinking to get the existing data from bigquery into another Kafka stream so that the incoming events can be matched against those data. Do you think this would be fine?

Comment: Given the volume of work/processing, I am thinking that you may have a relationship with a Google Cloud account team at your enterprise.  I'd be tempted to contact them and point them to this thread.  This feels like an opportunity for you and Google Cloud architects to sit down together and explain in depth what you are trying to achieve and have an architect consider alternatives and make a recommendation.   SO is great for ad-hoc Q&A, but I sense we are now in the realm of alternative designs and those are best served by direct conversation.